# What is the difference between APIView class and generics.GenericAPIView

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

What is the difference between  APIView class and generics.GenericAPIView

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`APIView` is a base class. It doesn't assume much and will allow you to plug pretty much anything to it.

`GenericAPIView` is meant to work with Django's Models. It doesn't assume much beyond all the bells and whistles the Model introspection can provide.

Answer (score 9):

APIView is the base class based view. Viewsets have APIView as a parent class.

With APIview you code methods etc for the different HTTP call methods such as post, get, put etc. These come with no standard configuration, so you can customise to your needs

With Viewsets, you code more specific methods . For example the ‘retrieve’ method, will expect arguments of the request and the pk of the object to be retrieved. Thus you write methods for create, retrieve, list, etc instead of post,get…

Moving on from that, you also have the routers. These work with viewsets and will create the urls for you based on how you coded the Viewset